# Music does not appear ncmpcpp

Tags: mpd, ncmpcpp

I don't understand why the music doesn't appear at all in `ncmcpp`, and I think the configuration is correct.

Music does not appear:

[image]

mpd.conf

```
bind_to_address   "localhost"
port              "6600"
music_directory   "~/Music"
playlist_directory "~/Music"
db_file           "~/.mpd/database"
log_file          "~/.mpd/mpd.log"
pid_file          "~/.mpd/pid"
state_file        "~/.mpd/state"
sticker_file      "~/.sticker.sql"
 log_level        "default"
 auto_update      "yes"
 auto_update_depth  "3"
 input {
         plugin "curl"
 }
 
audio_output {        
      type        "pulse"         
      name        "Pulse Audio" 
}

audio_output {
     type                    "fifo"
     name                    "my_fifo"
     path                    "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
     format                  "44100:16:2"
}
```

ncmpcpp/conf

```
mpd_music_dir = "~/Music"
#song_list_format = " $5%l $1║{$7 %a $1│$2 %t$1 $R $3%b$1 }|{$6 %f $1}"
#tag_editor_album_format = "{$4(%y)$9 }$7%b$9"
browser_playlist_prefix = "$8playlist$9"
selected_item_prefix = "$0"
selected_item_suffix = "$9"
user_interface = "alternative"
mpd_host = "127.0.0.1"
mpd_port = "6600"
system_encoding = "utf-8"

####visualizer settings####
visualizer_data_source = "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
visualizer_output_name = "visualizer"
#visualizer_sync_interval = "20"
visualizer_type = "spectrum"
visualizer_color ="yellow"
visualizer_look = "º|"

####songs####
#([cyan,date],[cyan, length], [cyan,title] | [cyan,date],[blue,title],[cyan])
song_list_format = "{$7%a $7%l $7%t}|{$7%a $5%t $7}"
#([red,artist],[magenta],[red,length])
song_status_format = "$2%a $7• $4%t $7• $3%b {}$7• $5%y$7"
#([cyan,length],[blue,title],[end current color])
song_library_format = "$7%l $5%t$9"
#([magenta,blue,magenta]|[blue]
now_playing_prefix = "$b$8»$2»$4»$3» "
now_playing_suffix = "$/b"
#([blue],[cyan,artist],[blue,title],[yellow,album],[magenta,length] 
song_columns_list_format = "(4)[]{} (15)[cyan]{a} (30)[blue]{t} (46)[white]{b} (5)[magenta]{l}"

####misc####
playlist_separate_albums = "no"
playlist_display_mode = "columns" (classic/columns)
browser_display_mode = "columns"
volume_change_step = "2"
progressbar_look = "─╼─"
#user_interface = "alternative"
data_fetching_delay = "yes"
media_library_primary_tag = "artist"
default_find_mode = "wrapped"
header_visibility = "no"
statusbar_visibility = "yes"
titles_visibility = "no"
header_text_scrolling = "yes" 
cyclic_scrolling = "yes"
#startup_screen = "media_library"
ask_before_clearing_playlists = "yes"
clock_display_seconds = "yes"
display_volume_level = "yes"
display_bitrate = "yes"
display_remaining_time = "yes"
ignore_leading_the = "no"
mouse_support = "yes"
#use_console_editor = "yes"
autocenter_mode = "yes"

####colors####
discard_colors_if_item_is_selected = "yes"
header_window_color = "red"
volume_color = "cyan"
state_line_color = "red"
state_flags_color = "yellow"
main_window_color = "white"
color1 = "default"
color2 = "green"
current_item_prefix = "$(red)$r"
current_item_suffix = "$/r$(end)
progressbar_color = "yellow"
statusbar_color = "red"
current_item_inactive_column_prefix = "red"
```

I've tried these commands:

```
killall mpd
mpd
mpc update
ncmpcpp
```

But the music doesn't appear at all, I tried opening the log in `mpd` and `ncmpcpp` to see if there was an error or not and there was no error at all.